# ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

In my web application when i upload a video and click the save button, if the video is uploaded i write the code to display the message video is uploaded. My code is as follows:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", false);
```

When the alert box appears is comes with a white background. I clicked on ok button in that alert box but the page is not going back to the previous page it is showing the same white space.

Can you solve the problem.? If you not understand i will explain clearly.

In local it is working fine but when i update in online it is not working.

Comment: This is not clear "the page is not going back to the previous page it is showing the same white space can you solve the problem"

Comment: Try a return true; after your alert and see what happens

Comment: hi Mr.Pandiya Chendur where should i write the code return true

Comment: ok i understand Mr. Pandiya chendur i will try and let u inform ok

Comment: Mr.Pandiya chendur it is giving error like this. i wrote the code after the 

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", false);
return true;

it is giving the error like....

7: Since 'Subadmins_uploadvideos.insertVideos()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Hey sridhar ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');return true;</script>", false);

Comment: You said (below) "Suppose default.aspx is there where i write the code to upload the video". What is the name of the "white background page"?  Is it different?

Comment: No Mr.Jdk No it is not a separate page but when popup box(alert box) fire it is comes with like white page

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hai sridhar,
  I found an answer for your prob

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", true);
```

change false to true

or try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ursavebuttonID, typeof(LinkButton or button), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", true);
```

Comment: No Pandiya Chendur my name is sasidhar

Comment: No Mr.Pandiya Chendur when i change false to true the alert message is not coming

Comment: button or linkbutton or image button

Comment: Actually i remove the ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", false);

and write the code response.write("<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>");

and it is working fine Thank you for response and spend time on my problems

Comment: make sure that response.write will be an issue in a web form application while you deploy to server... Any how you made it work

Comment: Ok i will take care other wise i will go for other option. I think you understand my problem. if you get the solution send the response thank you for your response. i think u r an India right.

Answer (score 1):

The method [System.Web.UI.Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(VS.80).aspx) has been **deprecated** for some time (along with the other Page.Register* methods), ever since .NET 2.0 as shown by MSDN.

**Instead use the .NET 2.0 [Page.ClientScript.Register*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager_members(VS.80).aspx) methods.** 
- (The ClientScript property expresses an instance of the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager(VS.80).aspx) class )

**Guessing the problem**

If you are saying your JavaScript alert box occurs before the page's content is visibly rendered, and therefore the page remains white (or still unrendered) when the alert box is dismissed by the user, then try using the [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(..) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(VS.80).aspx) instead because it runs the given client-side code *when the page finishes loading* - and its arguments are similar to what you're using already.

Also check for *general JavaScript errors* in the page - this is often seen by an error icon in the browser's status bar. Sometimes a JavaScript error will hold up or disturb unrelated elements on the page.

Comment: No Mr.jdk i am not getting any javascript erros in the page

Comment: i am not going to my page where i upload the video

Comment: Do you need to redirect to another page after alert is dismissed by user?

Comment: No Mr.Jdk. see, suppose default.aspx is there where i write the code to upload the video, when video upload is over i write the ClienetScript.RegisterStartupScript() if video is uploaded one alert box comes in a white background page when i click on Ok  of the alert box it is not going back to default.aspx page, it is remain in the white background page i think you get my problem now

Comment: Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: Sorry Mr.Jdk actually i am in office it is not possible, it is confidential

Comment: Any way Mr.Jdk thank you for response spend time on my problem thank you

Answer (score 1):

See if the below helps you:

I was using the following earlier:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "AlertMsg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Web Policy need to be accepted to submit the new assessor information.');</script>");
```

After implementing AJAX in this page, it stopped working. After reading your blog, I changed the above to:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(imgBtnSubmit, this.GetType(), "AlertMsg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Web Policy need to be accepted to submit the new assessor information.');</script>", false);
```

This is working perfectly fine.

(It’s .NET 2.0 Framework, I am using)