# Difference between Response.Write() and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between Response.Write() and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Response.Write` method can be used to output code during the rendering phase of the page. The `<%= %>` server tag is a shortcut for `<%Response.Write( )%>`.

If you use `Response.Write` from the code behind, you will write to the page before it has started rendering, so the code will end up outside the html document. Eventhough the browser will execute the code, it doesn't work properly. Having something before the doctype tag will make the browser ignore the doctype and render the page in quirks mode, which usually breaks the layout. Also, as the script runs before anything of the page exists, the code can't access any elements in the page.

The `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` method is the preferred way of adding script dynamically to the page. It will render the script at the end of the form so that it doesn't break the html documnet, and it can access the elements in the form.

Also, you give each script an identity, which means that duplicates are removed. If a user control registers a script, and you use several instances of the user control, the script will only be rendered once in the page.

Comment: you mean response.write() will get before rendering the page in ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method will get after postback am i right? Mr. Guffa

Comment: @Surya: Both will add the code the page that is send to the browser, so the code will run when the page loads in the browser. The difference is where in the response the code is placed. Having the code before the document means that the browser runs the code first, then loads the rest of the response, which is the actual page. If you have Response.Write("<script>alert(1);</script>"); the window will be blank when the alert shows, and the page loads after closing the alert (likely distorted due to the ignored doctype).

Comment: Mr. Guffa you are saying that when we write Response.Write("<script>alert(1);</script>")the window will be blank when the alert shows, and the page loads after closing the alert, but when i used ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(gettype(),"sa","<script>alert(1);</script>",false) the window will be blank when the alert shows and the page loads after closing the alert, some times the window is in the  blank even we close the alert the page will not load it remains in the blank (white page)

Comment: @Surya: As the script runs before all elements in the page are complete, the page might not show up depending on how you have done the layout. If the page doesn't show up after the script is run, there is something more that is wrong with the page. View the source of the blank looking page to see how much of the page you got, and if there is any error message.

Comment: but it will be in the blank page

Comment: So, what does the page source look like for the blank page? If the script runs at all, you have to have most of the page as the script comes at the end of the form.

Comment: Mr. Guffa when i write ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()  the alert box comes in white blanck page. If I click on ok button some times it will remain in the same white blanck page it is not moving from white blanck page. I already post this in Stack Overflow if you want to see that one i will give the question name. thank you for response.

Comment: Yes, please link to the question.

Comment: Hi Guffa this is my question check out please 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905716/clientscript-registerclientscriptblock

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge difference.

Basically Response.Write will write to your response stream right now, normally this will put whatever you write at the very top of your page output, even before the  tag (unless you call it after the page render event).

When you use RegisterStartupScript it will wait and write your JavaScript to the response stream after the page's controls have rendered (IE, the controls wrote their HTML to the response stream). This means the JavaScript you register will be executed by the browser after the other HTML before it has been loaded into the DOM. This is very similar to the  event. Another thing this does is if “registers” the script so if you have more than one control on the page that both need that JavaScript they can check to see if it’s already been registered so it’s only rendered once and both controls use it client side.

Hopefully that makes sense, there are more details then that but I tried to keep it simple.

Comment: you mean response.write() will get before rendering the page in ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method will get after postback am i right? Mr.dukk

Comment: No, a postback is when the page refreshes but stays on the same page. This will happen the first time the page is requested.

Answer (score 0):

[Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585.aspx)

> The Write method writes a specified
>   string to the current HTTP output.

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

> Registers the startup script with the
>   Page object.

Comment: what is the meaning of Registers the startup script with the Page object. Mr. adamantium thank you for response

Comment: If you want to execute a script block after a postback you can use this method.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, both these methods are unrelated. Response.Write() can be used to write something on page that is rendered. While ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() can be used for registering a javascript on page start up.