# how to keep web page displayed during JavaScript alert in Chrome & FireFox for a VB ASP.NET web app

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to keep page displayed in background while alert popup is displayed?
(IE keeps it displayed)

In my VB ASP.NET web app, I popup an alert by using JavaScript alert().  (see code below)
But when alert pops up, Chrome and FF web page goes blank until user hits OK, then it is re-displayed.  (IE doesn't have problem)

```
' Shows javascript alert_message at browser, because MsgBox doesn't work there.
Private Sub alert(ByVal alert_message As String)
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "<script language='javascript'>"

    msg += "alert('" & POPUP_ALERT_TITLE & "\n\n" & alert_message & "');"

    msg += "<" & "/script>"
    Response.Write(msg)
End Sub
```

SAMPLE USAGE WITHIN MY VISUAL BASIC 2013 ASP.NET WEB APP..........

```
Function sample_usage()
    alert("INTERNAL ERROR 111.")
End Function
```

Comment: Try putting your alert into a short `setTimeout` delay - that will let page time to render. That said - do not use `Respose.Write` to generate client-side script. Use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` instead

Comment: What is the benefit of ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() ?

Comment: Here's a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/1926721/961695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
Private Sub alert(ByVal alert_message As String)
    Dim msg As String
    msg = "<script language='javascript'>"

    ' The 100 ms delay prevents a blank page during alert, in Chrome and FireFox:
    msg += "setTimeout(function(){alert('" & POPUP_ALERT_TITLE & "\n\n" & alert_message & "')}, 100);"

    msg += "<" & "/script>"
    Response.Write(msg)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript executes on a single thread. Alert boxes interrupt that thread, causing it to hang until the user closes it. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq2hezyw/) for an example.

```
<div id="messages">
</div>

<script>
alert('test');
$('#messages').text( 'alert is done!' );
</script>
```

What's likely happening is that you have some Javascript which is reloading portions of the page. IE is executing things in a particular order, and Chrome and Firefox are doing things in a slightly different order (or are doing things faster/slower). So in IE, the page underneath has finished (or not started) loading/reloading while in Chrome and Firefox the page is in the middle of loading/reloading.

Unfortunately, there's no simple solution to this... any answer will involve changing your Javascript a bit. I'd recommend using something like [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) and then showing things like alerts after a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) (to give other parts of your Javascript a chance to finish).

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this also:

```
Response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"">setTimeout(function(){alert("" type your message here"")},100);</script>")
```

Comment: I doubt it will work if you don't add the script tags. Also, the response is similar to the accepted answer except that it's in a single line and without the script tags.