# Font size increases after a Java alert box is clicked on and ASPX page

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I saw a great answer to this question on a PHP application. The fix for this was to put the Java Script in the body section because the css file attributes are ignored when clicking the Alert box. I have script for an Alert box in my code behind at aspx.vb page load that appears or remains invisible depending on what I send the page [?id=1] or [?id=2]. The link that gets to the page with the alert box on it sends [?id=1]. An if statement in code behind hides the box if it is [?id=1]. Once a person completes entering data on the page, he/she clicks a button that sends the user to an emailing page, which then redirects the user back to the page with the alert box and sends [?id=2]. The If statement page reads the [?id=2] and the box appears stating that their email went through. Click the alert [Okay] button and the fonts increase their size. Right now the If statement and Java script are in Page Load on the code behind. Where do I put the if statement (and how) so reload does not ignore the css file attributes.

Here is the If statement placed in page load. How do I put them on the ASPX page or do I?

```
    If Request.QueryString("id") = "2" Then
        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Your Early Order information has been sent to the Purchasing Department');</script>")
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If
```

Comment: I am not sure what _"css file attributes"_ are, but I think your problem might have to do with the `Response.Write` in your code. If you want to inject javascript in a .NET web forms project you should use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method call, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926449/difference-between-response-write-and-clientscript-registerstartupscript).

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Comment: As @zgood writes, you should use the ScriptManager. Because Response.Write puts the text at the very top of the page, even above the starting `<html>` tag. So this can result in strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace your `Response.Write` with `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.

You can read the reason and differences in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926449/difference-between-response-write-and-clientscript-registerstartupscript).

Your updated code would look like this:

```
If Request.QueryString("id") = "2" Then
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertScript", "alert('Your Early Order information has been sent to the Purchasing Department');", True)
 Else
     'Do nothing
 End If
```

Comment: That was exactly it. You are as your name says. Thanks a bunch.