# current response alert box seems not return to parent page actually

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer

I use the code below to make a message box.

```cs
public static void msgBox(string msg)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script language=javascript>");
    sb.Append("alert(\"" + msg + "\")");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb);
}
```

I find after I click confirm button in alert box, the page returns normally.

I press F12 to inspect:

- In IE11, the message box show again.
- In Chrome and Edge, it won't show message box again.
- In Firefox, the message box will not shown, but I see a line insert in the front of the HTML.

Is there anything wrong with the `msgBox` method? Thanks.

```html
<script language=javascript>alert("Message")</script>
<!DOCTYPE html >
...
```

---

***Update some references related to the discussion in answers.***

Reference for understanding `Response.Write` and `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

[Difference between Response.Write() and ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926449/difference-between-response-write-and-clientscript-registerstartupscript)

Reference for ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript & ClinetScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8)

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb);` is not the best way to inject a js cript in a page. It will write the js code in the response at the current place in the response creation process. So you have no certainty of to the exact position of the js code in the response.

I would recommend:

```
using System.Web.UI;

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "anyId", "alert(\"" + msg + "\");", true);
```

Another advantage is this works perfectly in case of Ajaxified response.

Don't forget to escape the " in msg.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the anwser. But in this system, many palces use this method, do you think there are any good reasons let me to advise my boss arrange replace this one? Maybe a large task. And I just discover this problem when I add a `waiting` message to hint users, it can't be hide normally. And I have to remove it for temparary.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript can be used in a static method of a static class in App_code. And the page can be statically retrieved by Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;. So everything can be static and is thus packageable in a method.

Comment: Hi, But I see this in Microsoft Docs . "If you want to register a startup script that does not pertain to partial-page updates, and if you want to register the script only one time during initial page rendering, use the RegisterStartupScript method of the ClientScriptManager class. "

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned the parent page, I am not sure if you are testing in C# Web Forms?

I tested it in a WebForms page with a master page. I called MsgBox() in the Page_Load event of the content page, but the browsers you mentioned have the same effect. After confirming the content of the alert box, nothing happened.

And the script code added before the html declaration should be the result in the Chrome browser and MS Edge. In IE or FireFox, the script code will be added to the page Head. Like this:
[image]

And I'm not sure how you tested it, can you provide more details, such as a minimal code example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for help. I test this again, and my result is converse with yours.

Comment: And today, I test more details and search more informations. I find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926449/difference-between-response-write-and-clientscript-registerstartupscript. This maybe the problem, I rewrite anoter `MsgBox()`  with `ClientScirpt.RegisterstartupScirpt()`, the alert use this new method will returen sucessfully in IE in my server. And others using old `MsgBox()` I posted above will still works wrong. I think that maybe the solution.

Comment: Yes, is's a C# web Form application. An old system, so many old logic and methods,  I try to find the reason /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~.