# how to run javascript code in C# crawler on server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have developed crawler in `C#`.

I am reading data from one page that is list page, It uses javascript for redirecting to next page.

function is - `<a onclick="redirectToNextPage(PageID)">More</a>`

How i can run this function in serverside and get url of the next page, so that by that url i can save that page.

**I want to run javascript function in C# to get url of next page**

Comment: can you show your code what you tried so far.

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myscript", "RedirectToNextPage('210')", true);

Comment: I have used this code @Illaya

Comment: Tried like this...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905716/clientscript-registerclientscriptblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll almost certainly need a headless browser to do that, not just running JavaScript code without the context it expects to run in. [This question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net) list some headless browsers that can be used from C# (not all of them have JavaScript support, though). That list may well be out of date now, but that's the term you need to search for.

Comment: i am downloading browser. But how it will help me?

Comment: @HiteshModha: Because a *headless* browser is run from code. So in code, you use the headless browser to load a page, then use its features to find the links, and use its features to tell it to "click" a link. In a headless browser that has JavaScript support, you'll be able to run the JavaScript associated with that link.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/.

It exposes Google V8 JS engine to CLI and also allows to CLI objects to be manipulated by JS