# JavaScript How to enabled button on client-side on CallBack and Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page with two buttons. One triggers and UpdatePanel (AJAX CallBack). The other a full page refresh (Postback).

I need to disable both buttons when any of them are clicked (This part i manage to make it work) and reenabled them when the Postback or Callback is complete. Wich event or where on JavaScript should I Call the function to enabled the buttons in both cases?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's some code. This is the buttons definition:

```
<asp:button id="cmdFiltrar" UseSubmitBehavior="false" style="width:48%" runat="server" CssClass="botonActivo" text="<%$ Resources:Idioma, Historico_Consultar%>"/>                                                 
<asp:button id="cmdExcel" UseSubmitBehavior="false" style="width:48%" runat="server" CssClass="botonActivo" text="<%$ Resources:Idioma, Historico_Excel%>"/>
```

on Page_load (Server Side) I define the JavaScript function to enabled/disabled the buttons, and add an attribute to both buttons to call it on click:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "EstadoBotones", "function EstadoBotones(bActivo) {document.getElementById('" + cmdExcel.ClientID + "').disabled=bActivo;document.getElementById('" + cmdFiltrar.ClientID + "').disabled=bActivo;}", True)

cmdFiltrar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + "EstadoBotones(true);")
cmdExcel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + "EstadoBotones(true);")
```

Now I need to know where to put this line of code (JavaScript):

```
EstadoBotones(false);
```

To re-enable both buttons.
Any Idea? Thanks!

**EDIT2**
As suggested by @Shouvik, I edit my code-behind in the page_load event:

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "EstadoBotones", "function EstadoBotones(bActivo) {document.getElementById('" + cmdExcel.ClientID + "').disabled=bActivo;document.getElementById('" + cmdFiltrar.ClientID + "').disabled=bActivo;}", True)

    cmdFiltrar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + "EstadoBotones(true);")
    cmdExcel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + "EstadoBotones(true);")

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ActivarBotones", "EstadoBotones(false);", True)
```

The last line gets executed on code-behind, but the buttons on client side did not get enabled like they should...

Comment: The ajax call has a success method, depending on what library you are using. Enable the button on success, and on error handle appropriately.

Comment: Share the relevant part of your code..

Comment: I post some code! please help!

Comment: So you are using deprecated code. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1905792/393459)

Comment: I change my code following your advice. But the problem persist. Any other idea? Thanks!